# read function's return value and the length of the buffer are not the same, C language, ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c

In ubuntu 12.04, I want to write a concurrent server, which can receive http packets from my virtual machine, then forward the packets to the original destination of my VM. But when I'm reading the packets using read function in C language, sometimes **the return value and the length of buffer are not the same** (for example: rbyte=1024, strlen(buf)=62 ). I've checked errno and find that errno=0, which means no error with the read function. I think that these two variables should be exactly the same, but for my program, they are not. The following is part of my code:

```
char buf[1024];
size_t rbyte = read(sFrom, buf, sizeof(buf) );
cerr << "length of buf: " << strlen(buf) << "\n";
cerr << "rbyte: " << rbyte << "\n";
```

I've read http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html to get some clues, but still don't know the reason of this error.

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Maybe because there are null-bytes in your stream and since `strlen` stops counting at the first instance of the null-byte character (\0), this may be why your length is smaller. `1024` is the size of your character buffer so this matches up.

Comment: You're passing too many parameters to `read()`.

Comment: do Dave, thanks for for reminding me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the linked documentation states, `read` reads bytes, not strings, so if the input conatins a zero byte, you will get a string that is less than the number of bytes read (remember, C uses null-terminted strings), which means the first null character determines the end -- and thus the length -- of the string)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a error. The 3rd argument of `read()` means the max bytes that can be readed. It doesn't block until reaching the size of 3rd argument.

The return of `read()` indicates how much bytes there were in the buffer at the `read()` request.

You should do a loop while not readed 'n' bytes (n = your message size). Or until `read()` returns 0 (for synchronous messages).

hint: If you write (client) null-terminated strigs, at server-side you can do a `fdopen()` on socket descriptor and use `fgets()` (streaming buffer), it block your code until a '\0'.

Comment: hint2: I never tried, but for linux 2.2, look at recv() with MSG_WAITALL ( linux.die.net/man/2/recv ). But, the loop into read() is the most common solution. Please, look Chris Jester-Young comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143123/how-to-create-a-buffer-for-reading-socket-data-in-c