# Image Stream sent over Socket - Server Deadlock Issue

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets, stream

I've implemented an Android application that takes a picture with the SP camera and sends it over a socket to the server.

I'm using the following (JAVA) code to read the image file stored locally and send it in successive chunks over the socket:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( "my_image_file_path" );

int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[16384];

try {
    while( (nRead = fileInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1 ){
        networkOutputStream.write( data, 0, nRead );
    }

} catch( IOException e ){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
fileInputStream.close();
```

And the following (C/C++) code to read it and store it on the server:

```
char newbuffer[MAX_BUF_SIZE];
int checkOperation;

ofstream outfile( "image_file_path".c_str(), ofstream::binary );

do{
    checkOperation = read( clientSocketDescriptor, newbuffer, sizeof(newbuffer) );

    if( checkOperation < 0 ){

        cout << "Error in recv() function, received bytes = " << checkOperation << endl;
        exit(1);
    }else if (checkOperation != 0 ){

       /*
        * some data was read
        */
       cout << endl << "READ Bytes: " << checkOperation << endl;
       outfile.write( newbuffer, checkOperation );

       /*
        * emptying buffer for new incoming data
        */
       for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(newbuffer); i++){
          newbuffer[i] = 0;
       }
    }
}while( checkOperation =! 0 );

outfile.close();
```

The Android client application seems to write correctly all the bytes in the socket, and successfully exits from the `while` loop.

However the server code gets stuck in the last iteration of its `while` loop, and isn't able to continue execution.

- Why can't the server read the `EOF`?
- Is my code for sending the image or reading it not correct?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help, since I'm really stuck!

Comment: because you don't send EOF ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not closing the `networkOutputStream`, so the C++ code doesn't know you're finished.

Either you need to close the output stream - which is only viable if you don't need to send any more data on it, obviously - or you need to include some metadata in the protocol to either indicate before you start writing how much more data there is, or include something afterwards as a "done" indicator. Generally I prefer a length prefix - it's much simpler than having to worry about escaping if the "done" indicator appears naturally in data.

A half-way house is to repeatedly say "here's a chunk of data length X" and then an "I'm done, no more chunks" message (which could be "here's a chunk of data length 0" for example). This way you don't need to know the total length beforehand.

Comment: I'm not closing the `networkOutputStream` cause I need to send some other data after the image (some text file with a description of the image). In your opinion, for my particular use case what would be the best procedure to follow?Thks for your time...

Comment: And also, flushing the stream after the image has been sent with the `networkOutputStream.flush()` method could solve the problem?

Comment: @Matteo: No, just flushing won't help - because the C++ code still won't know that you've finished. If you need to send other information, I would length-prefix each piece of data (i.e. one length prefix for the image, another for the text information etc). If it's tricky to find out the full length before you start to write, you could go for the chunking solution.

Comment: @Matteo If you're not closing the stream there is no EOF. You seem to think there is an automatic EOF after each set of writes, although how TCP would know where to put it is a mystery, and how there could be multiple EOFs on the same stream is another.

Comment: @EJP - I thought that the EOF would be put `automagically` when the client code exits from the `while` loop. Thks for pointing out it's not like that! ;D